# Vue.js binding is hiding parent divs and elements (not intended)

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm building a simple Vue.js page and my HTML snippet is as follows:

```
<div id="vueApp">
      <a href="#" class="button is-outlined" @click="showNextDiv" >Show Div</a>
      <div class="modal animated fadeIn" v-bind:class="{ is-active: isActive }">

     ...

     </div>
</div>
```

I'm using the Bulma CSS Framework and the "is-active" modifier makes the div active (as the name suggests).

My problem is that whenever I load the page the `<div id="vueApp">` does not show up neither does the button that makes isActive turn true.

This is my vue instance declaration:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#vueApp',
  data: {
    isActive: false
  },
  methods: {
    showNextDiv: function(){
      this.isActive = true;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dash character in your CSS binding makes the name an invalid javascript property name so you need to enclose it in quotes:

```
v-bind:class="{ 'is-active': isActive }"
```

I suspect there might be something in your console highlighting this error.

**UPDATE**

Should have included my jsFiddle showing that your JS and HTML code works if the `is-active` is wrapped in quotes:

https://jsfiddle.net/psteele/mzjb8wvb/

Comment: Thank you for your reply Patrick. I already did that but no avail, actually I thought I had copied it with the quotes. Either way it should not hide the parent div.

Comment: Updated with working jsFiddle. If it's not working for you, there must be something outside of the sample code you included in this question that is causing the issue.  Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: I understand how this works and why it works. However I am having some trouble because whenever I insert this snippet `v-bind:class="{ 'is-active': isActive }"` into the "modal" div, the "vueApp" and the anchor both disappear. And therefore I am not even able to press the button. Thank you in advance for your patience.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle reproducing your issue?

Comment: Between trying to get this to work in jsFiddle while making it trying to work in development mode, I made it work. It was probably the quotes having into account that I took them off and it stopped working. Thank you!